# Some problems were found with the configuration of task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices' (type 'GoogleServicesTask')

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm pretty new to android studio and I am doing my project and I am stuck because of this error and cant find a solution anywhere

> Some problems were found with the configuration of task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices' (type 'GoogleServicesTask').

- Type 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesTask' field 'intermediateDir' without corresponding getter has been annotated with @OutputDirectory.

Answer (score 48):

in build.gradle(Project Level) try upgrade google-services in dependencies

'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'

this upgrade as mentioned in here [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#2021-05-14)

[image: google-services plugin 4.3.8]

Comment: Thanks but why can't Gradle give useful errors!

Comment: How did you fix it? I can not find this file anywhere but it must be there to use firebase.

Comment: The build.gradle to modify is in android/build.gradle.  It will then be in your dependencies section

Answer (score 5):

Just upgrade to the latest version of ***com.google.gms:google-services***
in the **build.gradle(project..)** file.

If its not available then add the dependency
[image]

This worked for me and you can find the latest version of ***com.google.gms:google-services*** [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.gms/google-services?repo=google)

Comment: This solution worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

When you update android gradle build to latest version, Please make sure to update google service to the laster version too. The issue will be fixed!

Example in `gradle-wrapper.properties`

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.2-bin.zip
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
```

in `classpath` section inside `build.gradle`

```
classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:8.2.0"
```